# Passing data among components and apps

Tags: android, android-intent, memory-management, bundle, parcelable

The are different ways how to pass data among components and apps in Android. For instance, here are some of them:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, DestinationActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("key", "value");

or

Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putInt("someInt", someInt);
args.putParcelable("key", ParcelableObject);
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction("someAction");
intent.putExtra("key", arg);

or

fragment.setArguments(args);
```

As I know in java primitive values are stored in a stack and objects are placed in a heap. So, I would like to know what's happening when we call these methods: bundle.putInt(int) and bundle.putParcelable(Object), intent.putExtra("key", "string value") and fragment.setArguments(args) in Android.

Comment: You need to ask much more specific questions.  YOur post was rambling from sharing CPUs and operating system level concepts like partitioning memory between apps, to application level concepts like garbage collection, to framework questions about specific implementation details, to a mention of a function that isn't part of a framework and would be an implementation detail of a particular app.  Focus on one thing, and ask clear questions.

Comment: @GabeSechan thanks for your response. Edited my question.

Comment: Ok, that's an answerable level.  Give me a minute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not all that much actually happens.  Inside of Bundle is a Map.  putInt will convert the integer primitive to an Integer object, and put the Integer into the map.  putString will put the String object there.  putParcelable will put an object that extends Parcelable into the map.  That's all that happens at that time.

When startActivity is called, it will walk that map, and basically build a stream of data.  The format isn't JSON but it serves a similar purpose-  its a well understood format that can be parsed to values later on.  As it walks that map, it knows how to add primitives (int, double, etc) to that file.  It also knows how to do Strings.  For Parcelable objects, there's a function in the object that adds the object to the stream and one to parse it out of the stream.  It then takes that stream and asks the OS to pass that stream to the process that implements the intent.  THe Android framework in that application will parse the stream back into a map (creating new objects) and then pass it to onCreate.

Why do all this work?  Because the intent you run may not be in your process.  So it can't share them directly, it needs to make copies.  The extras is just a built in serialization method, making it easy to pass complex data.

Why do we sometimes use Bundle and sometimes Intent?  Well, every Intent has a Bundle inside it.  Calling intent.putIntExtra will call Bundle.putInt on the bundle inside that intent.  Its just a convenience method so you don't need to call intent.getExtras().putInt().

Comment: Thanks for your answer! That's true, what you wrote I've found in android source code. So, all that data are stored in ArrayMap<K, V> which implements Map interface. Thanks!